# Not able to view attachment in salesforce, when uploaded through Multipart Rest API

Tags: rest-api, api, rest, attachment, apexrest

**Below is the code which I'm trying to insert attachment through API not sure what is wrong, when I try to open 'Failed to load pdf' error comes or if I send image type file then that also doesn't open**

**HEADER

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary_string**

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_Attachment";
Content-Type: application/json

{  
    "Description" : "Marketing Q1 2011",
    "ParentId" : "00Q1700000BLt9F",
    "Name" : "Marketing Brochure Q1"
}

--boundary_string
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Body"; filename="2011Q1MktgBrochure.pdf"

Zm9yIHRoZSByZX..........DQoNCg0KDQoNCg0KDQo

--boundary_string--
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the data as "binary", but the data itself is base-64 encoded (apparently). Try adding `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` to the body's headers.

Comment: I've tried adding that but now it's not even sending the data it throws error. Added **Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64** just below **Content-Type: application/pdf**

Comment: @RaviRoy The other alternative is to include the actual binary data. You can't upload the base-64 version and expect it to be parsed correctly.

Comment: what will be actual binary data?

Comment: @RaviRoy The raw binary data. For example, a PDF should start off as `%PDF-` (I guess), while JPEG would start off as `ÿØÿà..JFIF..` (where . is an unprintable byte). You might want to search on your favorite search engine for what a binary multi-part form would look like.

Comment: I tried using the binary data.This time I'm able to open pdf but there is no content within it. Is there any other way to send large file through API ? I don't know why this is not working and it's mention in salesforce guide also and I'm trying exactly the same. Link from salesforce guide https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm